# Limiting .Toggleclass to one at a time?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

Currently have this code that swaps classes whenever an image is clicked , and it is inside a PHP Html Loop to create the image buttons for every content post, but I want to limit the class swapping to be one at a time, So if I click the image in another post, the other posts' images will return to default. Any ideas?

```
{LOOP: STORIES}
<script type="text/javascript">

 $("#{STORIES.story_id}6 :image").click(function() {
        widget.toggle();
        $("#{STORIES.story_id}6").toggleClass('buyy');
};
</script>

<span class="buy" id="{STORIES.story_id}6"><input type="image" class="TEST"></input></span>
{/LOOP: STORIES}
```

Comment: Hahaha okay bad tag, switched.

Comment: I meant `:image` selector in here `$("#{STORIES.story_id}6 :image")`, if you want to select the `img` tags, it should be `img` not `:image`.

Comment: I thought it selected the <input type="image"

Comment: @undefined http://api.jquery.com/image-selector/

Comment: You should not write jQuery this way, echoing it with PHP... A lot of unnecessary JS code repetition. Include a separate JS file and handle stuff there, with one piece of code. If will make it much easier also to toggle the classes on all elements. That's the best I can give you, working with this current solution will result in hack and slash.